# How to reduce number of clusters and identify rows associated with it using seaborn.clustermap and pandas

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I am trying to generate a clustered heatmap and I want to be able to reduce it to X number of clusters and go back to my original dataframe and annotate each row with the cluster identifier.

Here the code I have used so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import os

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path, "table.txt"),
                 sep="\t",
                 index_col=0,
           )

cm = sns.clustermap(df)
```

I have been able to retrieve the order of the rows like this:

```
reordered_ind = cm.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind
reordered_ind_names = df.index[reordered_ind]
```